# On mouse over show div not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table on every table when I move my mouse to show a pop up will appear the thing is when I move my mouse on the first one it shows me all, would there be a possibility to show only the one on which mouse is hovered over? as of I want to when the user hover's it shows the pop up of the one which the mouse is hovering over, not all the pop up should be shown as of now

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-bar-chart').mouseover(function() {
    $(".bar_graph").show();
  });

  $('.fa-bar-chart').mouseout(function() {
    $(".bar_graph").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin-top:80px;
}
i {
  position: relative;
}
.bar_graph {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"> Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
<tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should use a tooltip plugin like [qTip 2](http://qtip2.com/). That's what I'd do anyway :)

Comment: I don't use jquery, but you are showing ".bar_graph" with the dot. So definitely each element that have this class name will qualify for the method .show()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(".bar_graph")` selector will return all the elements with the class `bar_graph`,  You should use `this` to refer to the related `bar_graph` like :

```
$(".bar_graph",this).show();
//Or
$(this).find(".bar_graph").show();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-bar-chart').mouseover(function() {
    $(".bar_graph", this).show();
  });

  $('.fa-bar-chart').mouseout(function() {
    $(".bar_graph", this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin-top:80px;
}
i {
  position: relative;
}
.bar_graph {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"> Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
<tr>                             
  <td>Stock In Trade <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true">Show
    <div class="bar_graph">
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </i>
  </td>       
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked for me but I have a question while $(".bar_graph", this).hide(); you have used ".bar_graph" then a comma and used keyword this when can you refer me a link or explain me why is this used ?

Comment: You're welcome, it's just a shortcut of  `$(this).find(".bar_graph")` .. it will select the `.bar_graph` element inside the current element `this`.